How to control and merge all roles from multiple user groups. One user multiple user groups and one user groups multipl roles
I need to create a function dan can merged all roles from user groups so that one user can have access to all given roles.
public function GetRoles($id = 'new', $module = null) {
        $json = [];

        $groups = array_merge((array) ($this->auth['payload']['group'] ?? null), (array) ($this->auth['payload']['additionalGroup'] ?? null));
        $access = GetAccess($module ?? $this->module, $groups);

        $json['insert']   = ($id === 'new' && in_array('insert', $access)) ? true : null;
        $json['view']     = ($id === 'view' && in_array('view', $access)) ? true : null;
        $json['update']   = ($id !== 'new' && in_array('update', $access)) ? true : null;
        $json['delete']   = ($id !== 'new' && in_array('delete', $access)) ? true : null;
        $json['upload']   = ($id !== 'new' && in_array('upload', $access)) ? true : null;
        $json['remove']   = ($id !== 'new' && in_array('remove', $access)) ? true : null;
        $json['inactive'] = ($id !== 'new' && in_array('inactive', $access)) ? true : null;
        $json['approve']  = ($id !== 'new' && in_array('approve', $access)) ? true : null;
        $json['cancel']   = ($id !== 'new' && in_array('cancel', $access)) ? true : null;
        $json['reopen']   = ($id !== 'new' && in_array('reopen', $access)) ? true : null;

        return $json;
    }

function GetAccess($module, $groups, $role = null) {
    global $config;

    $rules   = [];
    $modules = ModuleMerge($config['modules']);

    if (isset($config['access'][$module])) {
        foreach ($config['access'][$module] ?? [] as $key => $value) {
            if (in_array($key, $groups)) {
                $rules = array_unique(array_merge($rules, $value));
            }
        }
    } else if (in_array($module, ['main', 'login', 'login_google', 'register', 'reset', 'newpassword', 'validate', 'contact_us', 'disclaimer', 'privacy_policy', 'security_policy', 'terms_condition', 'help'])) {
        $rules = ['view', 'insert', 'update'];
    } else {
        $rules = $modules[$module];
    }

    if ($role) {
        $rules = in_array($role, $rules);
    }

    return $rules;
}

function ModuleMerge($array) {
    $result = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $moduleKey = $array[$i]['module'] ?? null;

        if (!isset($result[$moduleKey])) {
            $result[$moduleKey] = [];
        }

        $result[$moduleKey] = $result[$moduleKey]
        ? array_unique(array_merge($result[$moduleKey], $array[$i]['roles'] ?? []))
        : ($array[$i]['roles'] ?? []);

        if (is_array($array[$i]['children'] ?? null)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, ModuleMerge($array[$i]['children']));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

User 1
Main Group -> ['Staff']
Additional Group -> ['Store Admin', 'Merchandise', 'Inventory SV']
Group Staff Roles -> ['View main dashboard', 'edit profile', 'upload profile picture']
Group Store Admin Roles  -> ['View store module page', 'add store item', 'update store item', 'delete store item', 'approve store item']
Group Merchandise Roles  -> ['View merchandise stock', 'insert merchandise recipient']
For now, user 1 only can access main group roles, the additional group roles doesn't merged thus make user has no access!
I'm expecting that the User 1 also can have an access to additional group roles.
Actual result ->
['View main dashboard', 'edit profile', 'upload profile picture']  

Expecting this result ->
['View main dashboard', 'edit profile', 'upload profile picture', 'View store module page', 'add store item', 'update store item', 'delete store item', 'approve store item', 'View merchandise stock', 'insert merchandise recipient']


I'd suggest you develop the according algorithm outside of your project. Think about what data you have and what the expected results are for the different users. For a question here, there's too much info missing, in particular what the input data is and both expected and actual output.

I hope one day someone can help me out

Can you provide a [mcve], corresponding to the "actual result" above? Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, your question is really not easy to understand, making it unclear, which in turn makes it impossible to really answer.
